# temp stays empty in getopt.getopt

Tags: python, python-2.7

When using the getopt.getopt() function in my python script the temp return value stays empty. What am I missing.

```
def ParseOpts(cmdName):
    shortForm = 'c:n:';
    longForm  = 'cluster=,node='.split(',');

    try:
        print sys.argv;
        temp, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv, shortForm, longForm);
        print temp;
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print 'error !!'
```

Command:

```
$ python helloWorld.py --cluster=Test --node=Test2
['helloWorld.py', '--cluster=Test', '--node=Test2']
[]
```

Comment: As a style note, the semicolons at the end of each line are unnecessary in Python and clutter up the code quite a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing `getopt`, which expects a list of *only* the arguments, by supplying it with the whole `sys.argv`. It immediately sees the text 
`"helloWorld.py"` (which it can't parse as a getopt argument) and assumes it's hit the end of its argument list. You want to skip the first argument, since it's the program name.

```
temp, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], shortForm, longForm)
```

Comment: Thanks solved the issue... Also see it in all my examples/posts I was looking at,,, selective reading problem ><